# importing HDF5 files to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, hdf

The title pretty much summarizes the situation. BigQuery seems to accept a number of data formats for uploads, but hdf does not appear to be one of them. What is the "canonical" way to upload an hdf5 file? (obviously I can convert the file to a bunch of CSVs but that seems clunky).

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the need for hdf?

Comment: @Danger14 Fair question.Let's say I have tables such as OHLC for different stocks. A natural (and compact) way to store them all is as an hdf with ticker as key. Of course, one can store them all as tables in a database, but thus is a little clunky. an alternative way is to normalize and add a "ticker" column (or, which is the same, a multi-level index for a pandas dataframe, which one can then export to a CSV and feed to BQ. Does not seem super elegant...